# Safely inserting value with a unique index

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following query,

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT TOP 1 forumViewID FROM rla.dbo.forumView WHERE fv_sessionID = 27392504 AND fv_topicID = 23971) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO rla.dbo.forumView (fv_sessionID, fv_topicID) VALUES (27392504, 23971); 
END;
```

I have an unique index that spans fv_sessionID and fv_topicID - so most of the time this query works as expected, only one "view" is generated per session, occasionally I get a error though:

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX__forumView'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.forumView'.
```

Is there anything to do to stop this, or do I just need to catch and ignore in these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is set  `Identity` as such `column`. It will handle automatically unique value

In this case use try and catch.

Comment: AS bother the columns are foreign its not possible to use a identity column in this way, I have implemented a TRY/CATCH and so far it seems to be doing the trick, so i shall accept this answer for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

As AKA said, the fv_sessionid should be an identity column to avoid this error.

Please try the below peace of code to avoid that error if you dont want to have the identity column.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT TOP 1 forumViewID FROM rla.dbo.forumView WHERE fv_sessionID = 27392504 AND fv_topicID = 23971)

      BEGIN

       INSERT INTO rla.dbo.forumView (fv_sessionID, fv_topicID) VALUES (27392504, 23971)

        IF ( @@ERROR <> 0 )
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

       IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Why should `fv_sessionID` be an identity column, its a foreign key, as is `fv_topicID`. this table may contain a session that has viewed many topics, and a topic that has been viewed by many sessions.